# Valid Proof that the Irrationals are Uncountable?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

So I originally wanted to prove that the reals are uncountable, but the best solution I came up with was to prove the irrationals are uncountable so therefore the reals must be as well. I suppose my first question is, is this valid logic?

Next take any countable subset of $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$, put it as $S$. Since it's countable $\exists \; a : S \to \mathbb{N}$ whereas $a$ is bijective. Because it's bijective, $\exists \; b : \mathbb{N} \to S$ similarly bijective whereas $b$ is the inverse of $a$. Now let's form an irrational, put it as $s$. Start with the number defined as '$0.$'. The $n$th place after the decimal place the $n$th digit of $b_n$ with one added to it (if the $n$th digit of $b_n$ is $9$ put it to be $0$). It's clear that this number $s$ is not in the set $S$ so it follows that any countable subset of $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ is a strict subset, so $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ must be uncountable (otherwise it would apparently be a strict subset of itself...).

Now since $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ is uncountable it follows that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

P.S. I tag this as topology because it's introduced in "basic topology" in Rudin

EDIT: as William and Thomas pointed out this isn't exactly valid, there is no guarantee that $s \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$. So we can say let $S$ be a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so $\exists \; a : S \to \mathbb{N}$ and similarly the inverse of $a$, $b : \mathbb{N} \to S$ and so form $s$ as the number $0.$ with the $n$th digit after the decimal point to be either the $n$th digit of $b_n$ (extending the number with as many $0$'s as needed) plus one or if that number turns out to be $10$, place $0$ there. Then it's clear that $s \not\in S$ so every countable subset is a strict subset so $\mathbb{R}$ must be uncountable. It then must follow that $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ is uncountable since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, and taking a countable number of things from an uncountable number of things will clearly result in an uncountable number of things.

Comment: This is essentially [Cantor's diagonalization argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument).

Comment: @WilliamStagner well that's pretty cool, just put that in an answer and you get the accept, thank you!

Comment: How do you know that the $s$ constructed this way is not rational?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews since it'll end up being an infinite decimal, and without any sort of pattern... I suppose I realize now that doesn't mean there /isnt/ a pattern

Comment: @ThomasAndrews for example, you could have $s$ end up being $0.3333 \ldots$ so hrm... I wonder if this could be tweaked to work

Comment: If you just consider $a:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and run the same argument, it doesn't matter if $s$ is rational or not. It will most certainly be real, but it won't be in the image of $b$.

Comment: @WilliamStagner aha very nice, but theres no guarantee that there will be an $n$th digit in the $n$th term of the sequence

Comment: Sure, just continue any terminating decimals with $0$s.

Comment: @WilliamStagner aha ok now it works :D

Comment: @DanZimm I think it would be fun for you to prove rigorously that if $A$ is uncountable and $B$ is countable, then $A\setminus B$ is uncountable.

Comment: What I like about this is that not only are the irrationals uncountable, which would have horrified the Pythagoreans (who were appalled by finding _even one_ [or possibly two -- John Baez has proposed that it was finding that the _Golden Ratio_ was irrational that put them over the edge]), but that you can easily go on to show that the _transcendental_ irrationals are uncountable, which horrified many in the 19th-Century. (Yes, Victorian mathematical horror...)

Comment: @WilliamStagner already on it ;) are you on chat?

Comment: @DanZimm I am now! :P

Comment: @WilliamStagner Mathematics chat room?

Comment: Having trouble logging in...

Comment: np see you soon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially [Cantor's diagonalization argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

If you came up with this by yourself, that is really impressive. It is widely regarded to be one of the most beautiful proofs in mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

See Theorem 2.14 of Rudin's PMA, the idea for which Rudin credits Cantor, who provided the **canonical argument** for the uncountability of the reals: See [Cantor's Diagonalization Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

How is your proof distinct from that proof?

Indeed, if you thought of this on your own, KUDOS!

See also Rudin's Theorem 2.43 (p. 41).

Comment: I didn't check out the proof, I looked at the theorem and tried to come up with my own solution, also I looked afterwards but was unsure of to whether this was still valid (considering I'm not doing binary strings)

Comment: It's very similar. I'm not implying you copied it! I just thought you might enjoy the similarities!

Comment: ah ok cool! yea I thought it was more witty the way his argument was formed, I tried for the longest time to figure out how to work with sequences rather than just a set of numbers, but he just uses a set of sequences, which was interesting

Comment: also I apologize, but William got to it before you, and I already gave him my accept! otherwise nice chatting and hopefully I'll see you around in chat ;D

Comment: Yes, the idea is taken from Cantor: if you represent the interval of reals in $(0, 1)$ in its binary expansion, the "sequence" of 0, 1, are in fact digits in the expansion of a real number in (0, 1).

Comment: Sorry...I was busy posting/answering when William commented...it's a well known argument.

Comment: do you mean following the decimal point? otherwise I don't think I follow (I don't think I know what a binary expansion is)

Comment: Yes, following the decimal point. E.g., $0.101100001110100010001...$, binary meaning base 2 number system whose only digits are 0, 1....

Comment: ah ok, thank you for enlightening me!